# Displaying true minus sign in ggplot2 bar graph embedded in rmarkdown document

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I am trying to get a true minus sign to display in the heading for a ggplot2 bar graph in rmarkdown using knitr to knit to pdf.

Here is the toy data:

```
gene <- rep(c("Gene \u2013", "Gene +"), times = 4)
group <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 2, length.out = 8)
prepost <- rep(c("Pre", "Post"), each = 4)
score <- rnorm(8, 7, 2)

df <- data.frame(gene, group, prepost, score)
```

Notice I have used the unicode `\u2013` for the true minus sign

Now plot the data:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(y = score, x = group, fill = prepost)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 0.1) +
            facet_wrap(~gene, nrow = 1) + 
            scale_fill_manual(values = c("#999999", "#666666")) +
            theme_bw()

p
```

The true minus sign displays nicely for the gene negative group here.

However when we include this same code in a chunk in rmarkdown:

````
---
title: "Why is a true Minus Sign so Hard To Find?"
author: "Llew Mills"
date: "28 May 2016"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Plot

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)

gene <- rep(c("Gene \u2013", "Gene +"), times = 4)
group <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 2, length.out = 8)
prepost <- rep(c("Pre", "Post"), each = 4)
score <- rnorm(8, 7, 2)

df <- data.frame(gene, group, prepost, score)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(y = score, x = group, fill = prepost)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 0.1) +
            facet_wrap(~gene, nrow = 1) + #splits into two graphs: gene negative and gene positive
            scale_fill_manual(values = c("#999999", "#666666")) +
            theme_bw()
p
```
````

The minus sign has been replaced with `...`

Does anyone know how to get the true minus to display in rmarkdown knitting to pdf?

Comment: Works fine for me (Win 8 x64; pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX; `knitr_1.12.3`; `rmarkdown_0.9.2`)

Comment: Works fine for me Win 8 x64; XeLaTeX, rmarkdown_0.9.6

Comment: I am using rmarkdown_0.9.5 and knitr_1.13. But I am using a mac. Not sure what type of LaTex I am using. I think MacTex? If I switch warnings on a page and a half of warnings in the knitted document, all variants on `Warning in grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :## conversion failure on'Gene –'in'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <93>`